# How to find out what dependencies in my maven pom have a particular dependency.

Tags: java, maven

I need to exclude an artifact where I know the group ID, artifact ID and version of what I want to exclude but how can I find out what dependencies in my pom have this particular artifact as a dependency. I'm using maven 2x, don’t see a way for global exclusions. Does anyone know how I can find out what the offending dependencies are without having to look at each one?

I've looked around and can't find any answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dependency:tree` can help you here.  From the [Maven dependency plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html):

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections
```

will tell you what is pulling in `commons-collections`:

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |        \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.0:compile
```

Comment: Thank you Ian, understanding the dependency:tree seems like a good thing to know!

Comment: This answer is great (upvote).  But I "love" how the example at the link (copied here) uses an example where the groupid and artifactid are exactly the same. ("commons-collections:commons-collections").  Geeze louise.

Comment: Future readers.  It seems to like the groupid more than the artifactid, but I'm guessing.  I am seeing some results by using the groupid.  Again, maven.org, why did you use an ambiguous example in your documentation??  And not give any notes to the "includes" argument.  Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.